# Couldn't parse json string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have a json string and tried to parse using json.net but got JsonReaderException (Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Path 'MedicineQuantityList[0]', line 2, position 8.)

```
{
    "QuantityList":
    [
        "List": [7,10,14,21,30,50,90,100,200,300],
        "Default":100
    ]
}
```

I am new to json and i am trying to figure it out, how to fix it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: your json is not valid 
{
 "MedicineQuantityList": [{
  "List": [7, 10, 14, 21, 30, 50, 90, 100, 200, 300]
 }, {
  "Default": 100
 }]
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON format is invalid... Keep in mind that '[' is for arrays.

{"QuantityList":**{**
     "List":[7,10,14,21,30,50,90,100,200,300],
     "Default":100
 **}**}

Try your JSON samples by converting them on this site: http://convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm